# linux kworker's CPU percentage extremely high

Tags: linux, graphics-card, cpu, linux-kernel

I have a laptop with i7 processor and ATI video card, all the distros I'v installed have a common problem -- there is always a kworker(kernel thread) occupy 40% of the CPU, (i.e. one of the 8 logical CPU is always 90% ), and the system feels a little laggy. I have an old laptop with much less horse power (intel integrated video card and low performance duo core processor) but perform much better running the same distro

PS:

currently using Mint15 with 3.8 kernel, but it happens in ubuntu, fedora, with other version of kernel too

here is the out put of ps

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      8546 16.6  0.0      0     0 ?        S    00:23  14:54 [kworker/0:0]
root      9551 17.4  0.0      0     0 ?        S    00:56   9:48 [kworker/0:1]
```

here is the output of lsof

```
sheep-mint-laptop ~ # lsof -p 9551
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/sheep/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
kworker/0 9551 root  cwd       DIR    8,2     4096    2 /
kworker/0 9551 root  rtd       DIR    8,2     4096    2 /
kworker/0 9551 root  txt   unknown                      /proc/9551/exe
```

Comment: What distro? Which kernel version? Could you post `ps aux` output showing the process in question? The output of `lsof -p PID_of_kworker_process` (run as root)?

Comment: @terdon I'v added the information you asked, but this problem occurs in all my  linux installation on that machine, seems not kernel or distro specific, haven't try compiling kernel myself yet

Comment: In that case, also tell us what the machine is. What graphics card? What driver are you using? Which laptop? I'm not saying I know the answer but the more information you give, the likelier it is someone can find it. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask questions.

Comment: Read this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/233947

Comment: We are here to help you. :-)